# It may look like odd sentence but can I use it anyway?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The original sentence would be:

'what's this book release date?'

Can I say it as:

'of when is this book release date' Even if it sounds odd?

Answer (score 2):

Films and recordings are released: books are **published**.

We would usually ask, "What is/was the publication-date of this book?" (using **is** if it hasn't yet been published, or **was** if it has) or "What is/was the date of this book's publication?"

More informally we might ask, "When is this book to be published? What date?" Or, if it has already been published, we might ask, "When was this book published? What was the date?"

Your first question (with no **'s** after *book*) could be used in certain unusual circumstances, but your second couldn't. "Of when is" is not colloquial.

Comment: My thought was: 'Of when" of used as "from" and "is this book release date" the "date agreeing with the when from the beginning of the sentence, just to give a poetry style

Comment: Not a poetry style I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot say it that way.  Imagine what the statement version would be: **This book's release date is ______.**  There is no *of* - we don't say "This book's release date is *of* ____."

We are asking a *when*-question, so we structure it like any [wh-question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions).  The noun phrase we are asking about is "this book's release date", so the question version is just

> When is this book's release date?

---

You might be thinking about a different structure you've seen somewhere: **As of when will this book be released?**  *As of when* is basically a rather fancy and formal way of saying "when".

Comment: @stangson, I wanted to make a concordance with the words "when" from the sentence beginning and the date, get it? and the "of when", of meaning from

Comment: But "of when" doesn't mean "from".  And even if it did mean "from", you wouldn't say "*From* when is the release date".

Comment: Is this a UK/US thing? Books aren't released here: they are published.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian In the US I would generally say *published* too, but it's not unusual to see "the book was released".

Comment: @stangdon, according to this: 'https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of' 'of' can be used to indicate origin, so 'of when' would be interchangeable for 'as of' get it? so it would be same as 'as of when is this book release date? as just a different way to say it from the usual

Comment: @stangdon: Thanks.

Comment: I1m just asking if thta could be possible some day you know, I mean it may be odd but it is possible right?